# Matrix Constructor Index out of range

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception, outofrangeexception

I am attempting to make my own matrix math class and here is the constructor that I am using.

```
    public Matrix (int numRows, int numCols) 
    {
        _matrix = new List<List<double>>(numRows);

        // initializes each list
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            _matrix[i] = new List<double>(numCols);
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to use it tho, It throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on the line

> _matrix[i] = new List(numCols);

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why arent you using ' double [][]'?

Comment: Later in the project I will need the same information located in the upper left corner of a larger matrix.  If I use two dimensional arrays, I will need to create a new array at that point (which wouldn't be a huge problem).  I just chose lists so that I could increase the size later without creating anything new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [List(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) `capacity` constructor argument does *not* set the number of elements; it sets the capacity. The capacity is the size of the *internal* array - not the number of elements actually realized by the collection.

Since the new List has 0 elements, due only setting the internal capacity, `_matrix[anyValue]` is Out-Of-Range.

---

If desiring a LoL (List of List) for the matrix, it's pretty easy to create with LINQ.

```
_matrix = Enumerable.Range(0, numRows)
            .Select(r => (new double[numCols]).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Alternative LoL generation that manually adds each column to a row, and then each row to the matrix.

```
_matrix = new List<List<double>>();
for (var r = 0; r < numRows; r++) {
    var row = new List<double>();
    for (var c = 0; c < numCols; c++) {
        row.Add(0);
    }
    _matrix.Add(row);
}
```

Or using AoA (Array of Array) and a `double[][]` result; Lists are better when the size changes, which might not be applicable here.

```
double[][] m = Enumerable.Range(0, numRows)
                 .Select(r => new double[numCols])
                 .ToArray();
```

Or even with a [Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), which may be more suitable than the above. Since arrays are not resizable, unlike the "List capacity" argument, the size sets the bounds.

```
double[,] m = new double[numRows,numCols];
```

---

See these questions, which also are related to incorrect usage of the constructor parameter

- [C# List<GenericClass>(100) Construction Principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147486/c-sharp-listgenericclass100-construction-principles)
- [C# - Index was out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249446/c-sharp-index-was-out-of-range?rq=1)